# Android Canvas: How do I draw multiple bitmaps with their own rotations and pivot points?

Tags: android, android-canvas

Suppose that I have two bitmaps that I'd like to draw on a `Canvas` of a `View`. The twist is that I want to draw the first bitmap rotated 30 degrees clockwise around one pivot point, and I want to draw the other bitmap 45 degrees counter-clockwise around another pivot point.

I have the following stub in mind:

```
canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
canvas.rotate(30, pivotX, pivotY);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapOne, x1, y1, antiAliasPaint);
canvas.rotate(-75, otherPivotX, otherPivotY);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapTwo, x2, y2, antiAliasPaint);
canvas.restore();
```

Edit:

Confirmed that it doesn't work. It just results in rotating the same canvas.

Will I have to create 2 `Bitmap`s, rotate bitmapOne in one new `Bitmap` object, rotate bitmapTwo in the other, and draw them as normal in the destination canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
canvas.rotate(30, pivotX, pivotY);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapOne, x1, y1, antiAliasPaint);
canvas.restore();

canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
canvas.rotate(-75, otherPivotX, otherPivotY);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapTwo, x2, y2, antiAliasPaint);
canvas.restore();
```

Comment: It works. I haven't explored how `canvas.save()` and `canvas.restore()` works, so I didn't know this. Thanks.